# node ejs reference error data not defined at eval when handing data to view

Tags: node.js, express, view, ejs, embedded-javascript

i've been closing in on a node application using express and ejs, but when i try to hand data to my view from the controller like so

```
var myData = {
  theData: data
};
res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/../views/index'), myData);
```

i get a nice error

```
ReferenceError:.. myData is not defined eval (from ejs lib)
```

when trying to access myData in the view like so

```
var data = <%-myData%>;
```

or in any other way basically, i've tried stringifying the data, wrapping it in another object and stuff like that but it still just won't show up, i have the feeling i'm missing something really basic here, does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The second argument you pass to `render()` is an object *containing* the view variables you want to use in your template. So the error you are seeing makes sense. If you want to use `myData` in that way you'd have to do something like this in your controller/app:

```
res.render(..., { myData: JSON.stringify(myData) });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a silly mistake I make when I try to send data from the server.
Here's the mistake:
 **var data = <%=myData%>;**
What you should do when passing it:
 **var data = <%-myData%>;**
It's supposed to be a dash NOT an equal before the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

If your are generating the template with the **HtmlWebpackPlugin** plugin, the data should be passed in your webpack configuration file, along with the `templateParameters` property.

For example:

```
...
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: __dirname + "/src/views/index.ejs",
        template: "./src/views/index_template.ejs",
        templateParameters: {
            myData,
        },
    }),
],
...
```