# EJS: Error while using "<%= %>" tag more than 1 time

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to implement EJS with node(js) and express(js).
I have created an array variable named "kindOfDay" with name of days in strings as, "Sun", "Mon"...
Inside views folder for EJS, I have a list.ejs file.
Problem is, whenever I am using <%= %> tags more than 1 time, it displays a reference error that "kindOfDay" is not defined.
Below is the content for list.ejs file.

```
  <body>
    <% if (nameOfDay == "Sun") { %>
      <h3><%=kindOfDay%></h3>        <!-- First "<%= %>" tag -->
    <% } else { %>
      <h3><%=kindOfDay%></h3>        <!-- Second "<%= %>" tag -->
    <% } %>
  </body>
```

If I will remove any one of the tag from the two, it will work just fine, no referencing error or anything.
What could be the problem?

Comment: [node ejs reference error data not defined at eval when handing data to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278565/node-ejs-reference-error-data-not-defined-at-eval-when-handing-data-to-view) this link seems similar problem. I hope this will be helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10357400/jain Thanks for your answer :) I found the problem was with render().

Answer (score 0):

the error was solved. The problem was in the node server script.
I had 2 res.render() functions and when the first one was getting executed, another res.sender() wasn't getting executed. That incomplete calling made the variable unique to the list.ejs file and reported an error as "variable not defined."

So, in the app.js file I changed this:

```
  // day variable is a string with 2 values, either "weekday" or "weekend",
  // controlled with if-else statement.
  res.render('list', {kindOfDay: day}); // Only this one is executed.
  // currentDay is a number between 0 and 6 representing week days.
  res.render('list', {nameOfDay: dayName[currentDay]}); // Variable not defined error.
```

to:

```
  // No errors now.
  res.render('list', {kindOfDay: day, nameOfDay: dayName[currentDay]});
```